# Were nephews and nieces sometimes referred to as cousins in 18th century Cornish wills?

Tags: england, 18th-century, cornwall, kinship-terminology, probate-records

I have copied a sizable chunk from [The Will of William Bond [Clothier in Ladock, Cornwall], dated 7 April 1747](http://www.cornwall-opc.org/Records/parishes/L-P/ladock_will_bond.php), below, and would like to draw your attention to the parts that I have highlighted in bold:

> I Give and Bequeath to my Trusty and **beloved Brothers in Law** William
>   Courtenay and **Thomas Courtenay** Taylors and my dearly Beloved Brother
>   John Bond Clothier Joyntly all of the parish of Laddock aforesaid all
>   my Goods Chattells Money Security for Money and all other my Effects
>   of whatever kind they be in Trust nevertheless for the Sole Use
>   Benefitt and Behoofe of my Beloved Wife Ann Bond That is to say that
>   they do and tis my Earnest desire and Order and Appointment from time
>   to time and at all times during her Natural life take especial Care of
>   and provision make for my said Beloved Wife Suitable to her wants and
>   as the Exigencies and Necissityes of her case shall or may require out
>   of my said Goods Chattells and Effects and tis my Further Will and
>   Pleasure that immediately after the Demise of my said Wife Ann Bond
>   That whatever of my Goods Effects or the produce of them be left
>   unspent in her maintainance and Buriall be in and remain forever to my
>   **Beloved Cousing John son to Thomas Courtenay abovesaid** and tis my
>   further Will and pleasure That if my said Cousin John Courtenay shall
>   appear at the death of my said Wife to be worth Fifty Pounds Clear and
>   free of all Demands and Incumbrances whatsoever That then out of the
>   Overplus I do give to my Brother John Bond Ten Pounds to my Brother
>   Phillip Bond Ten Pounds To my Sister Joan Courtenay Fifty Shillings To
>   my sister Mary Jolly fifty shillings to my sister Grace Williams to my
>   **Cousin Grace Daughter of my Brotherinlaw Matthew Courtenay**

Only one Thomas Courtenay is mentioned in the will and he is clearly described as being a brother-in-law to William.  However Thomas' son John is described as being a cousin to William when I would have called him a nephew.  Thomas' wife being called Joan (they are my 2nd great grandparents) fits with what I know of them, and they had a son John.

Further on in the will, Grace, the daughter of his Brother-in-law Matthew Courtenay, is described as being a cousin too, whereas I would have called her a niece.

Were such nephews and nieces sometimes referred to as cousins at that time and place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary (OED) one meaning of cousin is:

- A collateral relative more distant than a brother or sister; a
  kinsman or kinswoman, a relative; formerly very frequently applied to
  a nephew or niece. Obsolete.

The last quotation applicable to this meaning is dated 1747 (S. Richardson *Clarissa* I. vi. 36). (*I only just noticed that's the perfect match to your will's date!*)

The strict modern sense is instanced as early as circa 1290, so the term spends some time meaning just about anything (presumably this is why the term Cousin-German was used - to denote a full cousin in today's sense as distinct from other sorts.)